# Can I use 'Deferred' XEPs, like "XEP-0142: Workgroup Queues"?

Tags: xmpp

I want to implement the functionality same as defined in the XEP-0142  (Users to contact a representative of an organization or workgroup without knowing the address of a particular member of that organization or workgroup).

But in XEP-0142 site says "Implementation of the protocol described herein is not recommended". What are the consequences if we use the same?

I find the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837281/chat-application-with-queues-xep0142 on satckoverflow but there i could not find any solution for that one.

Please suggest me if i can use that one with out any problem or please suggest me any other alternatives to implement that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consequence depends on your requirements. If you have control over the functionality of both your client and server then you do not have any problem with implementing this feature. If you do not, it could mean that either the client or the server will not have this functionality implemented.

The advise just states that XMPP does not support this implementation anymore, meaning that software vendors who develop XMPP based solutions may or may not have implemented this feature as described.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kay Tsar.

Comment: "The advice … states … not support this implementation anymore, … may or may not have implemented this feature as described". [That is **not** what the advise states, nor what 'Deferred' means.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30259875/194894).

Comment: Your link states the following: "Implementation of the protocol described herein is not recommended." I am not a native speaker, so I might have confused advise with recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Openfire has reliable implementation of this XEP named fastpath. See fastpath plugin of openfire (and Spark) for more information.

So you can reuse Spark client or write your own to achieve needed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Most people are confused or warned by the current text a 'Deferred' XEP accompanies, which reads

> WARNING: Consideration of this document has been Deferred by the XMPP
>   Standards Foundation. Implementation of the protocol described herein
>   is not recommended.

this should have been changed a long time ago to<sup>1,2</sup>

> WARNING: This document has been automatically *Deferred* after 12
>   months of inactivity in its previous *Experimental* state.
>   Implementation of the protocol described herein is not recommended for
>   production systems. However, exploratory implementations are
>   encouraged to resume the standards process.

Which more precisely describes the situation a 'Deferred' XEP is in: It just hasn't been updated in more then 12 months. If someone would step up, and continue working on the that, which is something **everyone** can do, then it could back on the standards track:

> Note that if a XEP is Deferred, the XMPP Extensions Editor may at some
>   point re-assign it to Experimental status

<sup>from [XEP-0001 § 8.1 Standard Track XEPs](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0001.html#approval-std).</sup>

[XEP-0001](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0001.html) describes the process in detail.

1: http://logs.xmpp.org/council/2013-07-24/#15:12:32

2: http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/council/2013-August/003748.html